# BigTable: will column qualifier or timestamp filter cause the full scan?

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

Say I have a table that contains billions of records.

1. On a particular day there are only 7 records though. If I filter it by timestamp range (as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/using-filters#timestamp-range)), will it cause the full table scan?
2. Only one row has a column `"col36847629"`. if I apply a column qualifier filter, will it scan the entire table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any filters on Bigtable reads (besides ones related to the rowkey) will cause a full table scan if not contained by a rowkey or range. The filters are in place to help [reduce the amount of data sent over the network for lower network costs and faster throughput](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/filters), but are not going to reduce the size of the scan.

If this is a common scenario you're facing, you might want to add some date or timestamp information into your rowkey as a way to filter on that and then perform the scans.

Comment: Thank you, Billy! But if I have a key with a date, like, say "flowers#2022-04-04#fl268736", if I have too many records per day, the "fl***" is distributed well, but the date is too narrow. Will it cause hot spots if it has to switch to a new narrow key prefix every day? I mean, it might create a hot spot for a while, until the system adapts and assigns more nodes to the new prefix, or I don't understand it correctly?

Comment: I mean "I need to add a lot of records every day"

Comment: That idea could work, but you might want to experiment and see if it works in actuality. It could also be impacted by other prefixes instead of just having `flower#`. Also, it depends on the kinds of reads you're doing. If you only need the latest data, you could just duplicate the data in rowkeys specifically for the latest data or just make a new table to store the latest and use a garbage collection rule for a few versions.